# How to transform an entire function in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas

I want to transform the head of a dog to turn, but I don't know how to select an entire function and not more and transform this into an animation.

```
// The function
Head();

rotate();
// this is for the entire canvas, but how to do it specifically for a function
context.rotate(rotation);

rotation += 0.04
```

I am also not very familiar with animating in html canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `save()` the context before the transformation. Next you call the function that draw the head. Then you `restore()` the context. In this way the head will be transformed nut not the rest of the canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 300,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 300,
  cy = ch / 2;

let rotation = 0

function background(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle="gold";
  ctx.fillRect(20,20,160,50);
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle="gold";
  ctx.fillRect(120,220,160,50);
}

function Head(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "skyBlue";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,40,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(-15,-5,8,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle="white";
  ctx.fill();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(15,-5,8,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle="white";
  ctx.fill();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0,0,30,Math.PI/10,9*Math.PI/10);
  ctx.strokeStyle="white";
  ctx.stroke();
}

function frame(){
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  rotation += 0.04;
  ctx.clearRect(-cw,-ch,2*cw,2*ch);
  background()
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(cx,cy);
  ctx.rotate(rotation);
  // The function
  Head();
  ctx.restore();
}

frame()
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```